# Add details from email_activation db to member db after email code and captcha activation

Tags: php, mysql

How can we add all details in email_activation db to member db at check activation script.php?Move the details in sql database.

```
<?php
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $privatekey = "your_private_key";
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
 // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
 die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
 "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
 } else {
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $activation_code = $_POST['activation_code'];
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_name = "databasename";
 $db_use = "root";
 $db_pass = "password";
 $link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_use, $db_pass);
 mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
 $command = "UPDATE email_activation SET check_activation='$activation_code' WHERE username='$username' and activation='$activation_code'";
 $result = mysql_query($command);
 if ($result) {
 echo "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated …";
 }else{
 echo ("You've entered an invalid username / activation code – please retry");
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql`. it's depreciated and will be removed eventually. Use `mysqli. Also, escape your data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`:

```
INSERT INTO member (username, fullname, email) 
  SELECT username, fullname, email FROM activation WHERE id = ?
```

But why don't you just insert all data immediately into the member-table with a flag that activation isn't complete?

Comment: thanks Peter,can we direct to homepage using the script I posted?

Comment: Yes, use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); exit;` instead of your `echo "Congrats"`